# Java: conform static class (not instance) to an interface

Tags: java, static, delegates, static-methods, observer-pattern

Given an example class:

```
public final class TestClass {
   public static void initialize(final Activity activity, final String myString) {
   //this is a static method
   }
}
```

And an interface:

```
    public interface IObserver {
        void myMethod();
    }
```

I'd like the **class itself** to conform to that interface, so that I'll have the following static method:

```
        static void myMethod() {
        }
```

And so that I'll be able to register the **class itself** as an observer:

```
anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass.addObserver(this); // doesn't compile
anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass.addObserver(TestClass); // I want this result
```

Is this even possible in Java, or should I refactor the `TestClass` to be a singleton (i.e. to have a single instance)?

**Note**: parameter passed to the **addObserver** method is weakly held.

Comment: You need a singleton.

Comment: @Sweeper sure the goal is easily achievable with a singleton. However, is there a way to get it done with static methods & class? Moving to a singleton would require a substantial refactoring and I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: You don't have to make `TestClass` into a singleton. You could just create a new singleton class that implements `IObserver`, that calls `TestClass.myMethod`. Alternatively, use lambda expressions/create an anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I think the first suggestion is to essentially have a "proxy" class, which is a good idea. Could you please elaborate on use of anonymous class / lambda expression, preferably with some code examples? It looks like a very elegant solution to me.

Comment: Regarding the weak reference: to make the observer survive, you need some hard reference, e.g. by creating a static field in TestClass.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff good suggestion, thank you. Although, in my preliminary tests, the observer survives (and prints info to the console) even without being strongly held by the reference. Is it related to the garbage collector behavior?

Comment: Absolutely yes, related to GC. With (only) weak references, GC is free to reclaim the instance, but this can happen immediately, at some time later or never. Typically it happens when running low on memory. It surely happens before OutOfMemory is signalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using weak references, then I strongly suggest a singleton.

---

Original answer:

You could use a method reference if the interface only has one method.

```
anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass.addObserver(TestClass::myMethod);
```

If the interface has multiple methods, you can make an anonymous class:

```
anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass.addObserver(new IObserver() {
    public void myMethod() { TestClass.myMethod(); }
    public void anotherMethod() { TestClass.anotherMethod(); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the latter solution seems to be the most elegant to me. What if an object passed to the `addObserver` method is referenced weakly?

Comment: You did not mention weak references in your question at all, and I cannot see how that is related to your question anyway. Is that a separate question that you want to ask? If so, please consider posting a new question. @RichardTopchii

Comment: added a note of the weakly held parameter. It is related directly, as I guess, it changes the possibility of using an anonymous class. Although, I'm not sure if it's possible to still use the suggested approach, so I'd appreciate comments on that.

Comment: @RichardTopchii You mean `anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass` holds weak references to its observers? Well, then I suggest you use a singleton. You _could_ in theory add another list of strongly referenced observers to `anInstanceOfSomeOtherClass`, and add another method `addStrongObserver` that adds to that list. You would call this new method when using anonymous classes, and call the old `addObserver` when adding an instance that is referenced by another object. But man, this breaks encapsulation too much.

Comment: How about holding an anonymous class as a variable in the `TestClass`?

Comment: @RichardTopchii Yeah, that's fine too. The call site would look exactly the same as a singleton (`TestClass.observerInstance()`), so I grouped it into the "singleton" basket, but now that I think about it, it's not really a singleton...

Comment: Yes, since that's not actually a singleton but just a variable/property, I'd avoid refactoring `TestClass`